# Adujst code to treat html tags

Tags: android

I'm using a java class the helps me justify my text ..but the problem is it doesn't appear to treat the HTML tags (they appear as text in my `textview`) ..how can i modify the behavior of this class? Thanks

**JustifiedTextView.java**

```
public class JustifiedTextView extends View {

    private void constructor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        mContext=context;
        mXmlParser=new XmlToClassAttribHandler(mContext,attrs);

        if (attrs!=null){
            String text;
            int textColor;
            int textSize;
            int textSizeUnit;

            text=mXmlParser.getTextValue();
            textColor=mXmlParser.getColorValue();
            textSize=mXmlParser.getTextSize();
            textSizeUnit=mXmlParser.gettextSizeUnit();
            setText(text);
            setTextColor(textColor);
            if (textSizeUnit==-1)
                setTextSize(textSize);
            else
                setTextSize(textSizeUnit, textSize);

        }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }


    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        calculate();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setText(int resid) {
        setText(mContext.getResources().getString(resid));

    }
```

The associated class: XmlToClassAttributeHandler.java

```
public XmlToClassAttribHandler(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
        mContext=context;
        mRes=mContext.getResources();
        mAttributeSet=attributeSet;


    }

    public String getTextValue(){

        String value=mAttributeSet.getAttributeValue(namespace, KEY_TEXT);

        if (value==null)
            return "";

        if (value.length()>1 &&
                value.charAt(0)=='@' &&
                value.contains("@string/")){
            int resId=mRes.getIdentifier(mContext.getPackageName()+":"+value.substring(1), null,null);
            value=mRes.getString(resId);
        }

        return value;

    }
```

This is just nonsense text so that the post would be posted ---Nonsense
This is just nonsense text so that the post would be posted ---Nonsense
This is just nonsense text so that the post would be posted ---Nonsense

Comment: when are you providing the html text to you text view?

Comment: i am extracting a text from my sqlite database , and in that text there is html tags which are kind essentials ..this java class does justify the text really good but it doesn't treat the html tags ..and that's what i'm trying to change

Comment: So you can get text from the html tags but your styles are not applied to textView?

Comment: Yes that's it unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
      setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Or this. 
trim use to remove extra space while trying to remove the "< p >" tag

```
setText(Html.fromHtml(text).toString().trim())
```

Comment: I've already tried it .but it's not possible since text=mXmlParser.getTextValue (which is a string ..i've posted the second class(Xml to Class) associated with the first class in the post).

Comment: i"ve tried both solution ..but doesn't work .. i did this :         setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(resid)).toString().trim());
but no luck